# How do you create scaffold in Rails without XML (HTML only)?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, scaffold

The default scaffold command creates code like the following:

```
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @model_name}
    end
```

My application is not using XML, so how can I configure scaffold (and other generators) to only create the HTML code, and eliminate the pesky `respond_to do |format|` block?

Working in Rails 3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nifty_scaffold from Ryan Bates: https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators